# How to throw "expressive" / console friendly exceptions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, ecmascript-2017, typescript-eslint

JavaScript noob here... I'm exploring various options for throwing exceptions.

### Throwing a string / primitive value

This seems to be bad practice for several reasons (catching, stacktrace, ...)

### Using `Error`

```
throw new Error("bad times")
```

This seems to be a common approach, but I'm not a big fan because I can't easily add extra information. I can't for example do

```
throw new Error("bad times", { reason: strangeObject })
```

I *could* `JSON.stringify` the extra information, but I like when I can expand / collapse the object in the console.

From what I can tell I won't get any farther with custom exceptions / Error-subclasses.

### Throwing `{ msg: "bad times", reason: strangeObject }`

This allows me to expand / collapse `strangeObject` nicely in the console. For exceptions throughout my application to be consistent, I'd need to repeat the `msg:` part everywhere, which I'm not a fan of.

I ended up going for the last approach, just to find out that the ESLinter complains about this approach:

> Expected an error object to be thrown  `no-throw-literal`

So, **my question is basically**: Can I use `Error` (or custom `Error` subclasses) in a console-friendly way, i.e. support expand/collapse?

Comment: AFAIK no, it's up to the browser in how they want to display the Error object, but in Node.js you can easily control how errors are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settled for a custom exception and a `window.onerror` handler:

```
class MyAppError extends Error {
  constructor(msg, details) {
    super(msg)
    this.details = details
  }
}

window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
    if (error instanceof MyAppError) {
        console.error(message, error.details)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

function throwSomething() {
    throw new MyAppError("I made a mess", {
        someDetail: "a value",
        otherStuff: "another value"
    });
}

console.log("Hello World");
throwSomething();
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gofbx8hn/))

Result looks like this in Firefox and Chrome, which I'm quite happy with.

[image]